# Error when trying to run sails server after updating nodeJS version

Tags: sails.js, bcrypt

I am working on a Sails Project. I just updated my version of nodeJS to v5.0.0 and now when I run `sails lift` on my app. I get :

/Users/davidgeismar/wefootpostgres/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
            throw e
            ^
    Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 47, got 46.
        at Error (native)
        at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:450:18)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
        at require (module.js:385:17)
        at bindings (/Users/davidgeismar/wefootpostgres/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
        at Object. (/Users/davidgeismar/wefootpostgres/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:3:35)
        at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
        at require (module.js:385:17)
        at Object. (/Users/davidgeismar/wefootpostgres/api/services/PaiementService.js:2:14)
        at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)

the binding.js file looks like this :

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var fs = require('fs')
  , path = require('path')
  , join = path.join
  , dirname = path.dirname
  , exists = fs.existsSync || path.existsSync
  , defaults = {
        arrow: process.env.NODE_BINDINGS_ARROW || ' → '
      , compiled: process.env.NODE_BINDINGS_COMPILED_DIR || 'compiled'
      , platform: process.platform
      , arch: process.arch
      , version: process.versions.node
      , bindings: 'bindings.node'
      , try: [
          // node-gyp's linked version in the "build" dir
          [ 'module_root', 'build', 'bindings' ]
          // node-waf and gyp_addon (a.k.a node-gyp)
        , [ 'module_root', 'build', 'Debug', 'bindings' ]
        , [ 'module_root', 'build', 'Release', 'bindings' ]
          // Debug files, for development (legacy behavior, remove for node v0.9)
        , [ 'module_root', 'out', 'Debug', 'bindings' ]
        , [ 'module_root', 'Debug', 'bindings' ]
          // Release files, but manually compiled (legacy behavior, remove for node v0.9)
        , [ 'module_root', 'out', 'Release', 'bindings' ]
        , [ 'module_root', 'Release', 'bindings' ]
          // Legacy from node-waf, node <= 0.4.x
        , [ 'module_root', 'build', 'default', 'bindings' ]
          // Production "Release" buildtype binary (meh...)
        , [ 'module_root', 'compiled', 'version', 'platform', 'arch', 'bindings' ]
        ]
    }

/**
 * The main `bindings()` function loads the compiled bindings for a given module.
 * It uses V8's Error API to determine the parent filename that this function is
 * being invoked from, which is then used to find the root directory.
 */

function bindings (opts) {

  // Argument surgery
  if (typeof opts == 'string') {
    opts = { bindings: opts }
  } else if (!opts) {
    opts = {}
  }
  opts.__proto__ = defaults

  // Get the module root
  if (!opts.module_root) {
    opts.module_root = exports.getRoot(exports.getFileName())
  }

  // Ensure the given bindings name ends with .node
  if (path.extname(opts.bindings) != '.node') {
    opts.bindings += '.node'
  }

  var tries = []
    , i = 0
    , l = opts.try.length
    , n
    , b
    , err

  for (; i<l; i++) {
    n = join.apply(null, opts.try[i].map(function (p) {
      return opts[p] || p
    }))
    tries.push(n)
    try {
      b = opts.path ? require.resolve(n) : require(n)
      if (!opts.path) {
        b.path = n
      }
      return b
    } catch (e) {
      if (!/not find/i.test(e.message)) {
        throw e
      }
    }
  }

  err = new Error('Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:\n'
    + tries.map(function (a) { return opts.arrow + a }).join('\n'))
  err.tries = tries
  throw err
}
module.exports = exports = bindings


/**
 * Gets the filename of the JavaScript file that invokes this function.
 * Used to help find the root directory of a module.
 * Optionally accepts an filename argument to skip when searching for the invoking filename
 */

exports.getFileName = function getFileName (calling_file) {
  var origPST = Error.prepareStackTrace
    , origSTL = Error.stackTraceLimit
    , dummy = {}
    , fileName

  Error.stackTraceLimit = 10

  Error.prepareStackTrace = function (e, st) {
    for (var i=0, l=st.length; i<l; i++) {
      fileName = st[i].getFileName()
      if (fileName !== __filename) {
        if (calling_file) {
            if (fileName !== calling_file) {
              return
            }
        } else {
          return
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // run the 'prepareStackTrace' function above
  Error.captureStackTrace(dummy)
  dummy.stack

  // cleanup
  Error.prepareStackTrace = origPST
  Error.stackTraceLimit = origSTL

  return fileName
}

/**
 * Gets the root directory of a module, given an arbitrary filename
 * somewhere in the module tree. The "root directory" is the directory
 * containing the `package.json` file.
 *
 *   In:  /home/nate/node-native-module/lib/index.js
 *   Out: /home/nate/node-native-module
 */

exports.getRoot = function getRoot (file) {
  var dir = dirname(file)
    , prev
  while (true) {
    if (dir === '.') {
      // Avoids an infinite loop in rare cases, like the REPL
      dir = process.cwd()
    }
    if (exists(join(dir, 'package.json')) || exists(join(dir, 'node_modules'))) {
      // Found the 'package.json' file or 'node_modules' dir; we're done
      return dir
    }
    if (prev === dir) {
      // Got to the top
      throw new Error('Could not find module root given file: "' + file
                    + '". Do you have a `package.json` file? ')
    }
    // Try the parent dir next
    prev = dir
    dir = join(dir, '..')
  }
}
```

Do you know what is going wrong here ?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this error. Did you try to reinstall saills, bcrypt and bindings after updating to node v5.0.0? Try to run npm install bcrypt, npm install sails and npm install bindings.

Comment: or run rm -r node_modules && npm install

Comment: thanks it works again !!!